# ROS Answers SE migration: rviz flick

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody have this problem  with ATI hardware and ubuntu 10.10?
If I active "visual-effects" on ubuntu the main window of RVIZ starts flickering

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDc5PXKjsQE

thanks
Augusto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9794/rviz-flick/) by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 430 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

partial solution (from the mailing list):

I tried with glxgears (and fgl_glxgears) and I saw the same flickering
effect, so I searched with google for the enviroment variable you told
me and I found something interesting.

<glxinfo | grep rendering> reports
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
to correct this behavior I typed

and the flickering on glxgears disapperas, and also on Rviz.

I noticed this: if I launch the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T I get
<<direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)>> but if I launch
konsole instead with ALT+F2 I get <>
I don't understand exactly what is happening, but the only other way
to solve the problem is disabling compiz like Nathaniel wrote. I think
that there is some method to launch a window/console without using
compiz even the system is using it, but I don't know how.

For now I put  at the end of .bashrc and
seems to work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2011-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0